# setting specific intent for the filtered items in list view in android

Tags: android

i have had this problem for the last two to three days....i am trying to set specific intents to each item clicked in the list view but the issue is that iam using the position parameter to get the position but is redirecting me according to the current filtered position yet i want the original position on the list view... i tried to use the getItem method within the switch case but but am confused which values i have to pass in the case: to match the position.any help is highly appreciated
below is the sample of the codes

customList

```
public class CustomList extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

Context context;
ArrayList<Countries> countrylist;
ArrayList<Countries> stringFilterList;
ValueFilter valueFilter;

CustomList(Context context, ArrayList<Countries> countrylist){
    this.context = context;
    this.countrylist = countrylist;
    stringFilterList = countrylist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return countrylist.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return countrylist.get(position);
}



@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return countrylist.indexOf(getItem(position));
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_eng_content, null);

        TextView countryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_names);
        ImageView countryImages = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_imgs);

        Countries countries = countrylist.get(position);

        countryName.setText(countries.getNames());
        countryImages.setImageResource(countries.getFlags());
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(valueFilter == null){
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length()>0){
            ArrayList<Countries> filterList = new ArrayList<Countries>();
            for (int i = 0; i<stringFilterList.size(); i++){
                if ((stringFilterList.get(i).getNames().toUpperCase()).contains(constraint.toString()
                .toUpperCase())){
                    Countries countries = new Countries(stringFilterList.get(i)
                    .getNames(), stringFilterList.get(i).getFlags());

                    filterList.add(countries);
                }
            }

            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values =filterList;
        }
        else {
            results.count = stringFilterList.size();
            results.values = stringFilterList;
        }

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        countrylist = (ArrayList<Countries>)results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

FrenchMenu class

```
public class FrenchMenu extends ActionBarActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

ListView listView;
private SearchView searchView;

ArrayList<Countries> countrylist;
CustomList adapter;

String[] countryNames = {"Algerie", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cameroon", "Cape Verde",
        "Congo Brazavile", "Côte d'Ivoire", "Djibouti", "RDC", "Egypte", "Eritrea", "Ethiopie", "Gabon","Ghana","Guinea Bissau"
        , "Guinea Conakry", "Kenya", "Lesotho", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Mali", "Mauritania", "Maroque", "Namibie",
        "Niger", "Nigeria", "Rwanda", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Afrique du Sud", "Sudan", "Tanzanie", "Tchad", "Togo"
        , "Tunisie", "Uganda", "Zambie", "Zimbabwe"};

Integer imgs[] = {R.drawable.algeria_flag,
        R.drawable.botswana,
        R.drawable.burkina_faso,
        R.drawable.burundi_flag,
        R.drawable.cameroon_flag,
        R.drawable.cape_verde,
        R.drawable.congo_braza,
        R.drawable.cote_divoire,
        R.drawable.djibouti,
        R.drawable.drc_flag,
        R.drawable.egypt,
        R.drawable.eritrea_flag,
        R.drawable.ethiopia,
        R.drawable.gabon_flag,
        R.drawable.ghana_flag,
        R.drawable.guinea_bissau,
        R.drawable.guinea_conakry,
        R.drawable.kenya,
        R.drawable.lesotho,
        R.drawable.madagascar,
        R.drawable.malawi, R.drawable.mali, R.drawable.mauritania, R.drawable.morocco,
        R.drawable.namibia,R.drawable.niger,R.drawable.nigeria,R.drawable.rwandan_flag,
        R.drawable.senegal_flag,R.drawable.seychelles,R.drawable.south_african_flag,
        R.drawable.sudan,R.drawable.tanzania,R.drawable.tchad,R.drawable.togo,
        R.drawable.tunisia,R.drawable.uganda_flag,R.drawable.zambia,R.drawable.zimbabwe_flag
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_eng_countries);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_eng);
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    /*
    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(FrenchMenu.this, names, imgs);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_eng);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);*/

    countrylist = new ArrayList<Countries>();

    for (int i= 0;i<countryNames.length;i++){
        Countries countries = new Countries(countryNames[i], imgs[i]);
        countrylist.add(countries);
    }

    adapter = new CustomList(getApplicationContext(),countrylist);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);




    //when the items in the list view are clicked

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            //String itemPosition = adapter.getItem(position).toString();

            switch (position){

                case 0:
                    Intent algeria = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    algeria.putExtra("url","http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/algeria");
                    algeria.putExtra("title", "Medicament en Algerie");
                    startActivity(algeria);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Intent botswana = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    botswana.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/botswana");
                    botswana.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Botswana");
                    startActivity(botswana);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Intent burkina_faso = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    burkina_faso.putExtra("url","http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/burkina-faso");
                    burkina_faso.putExtra("title","Medicament au Burkina Faso");
                    startActivity(burkina_faso);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Intent burundi = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    burundi.putExtra("url","http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/burundi");
                    burundi.putExtra("title","Medicament au Burundi");
                    startActivity(burundi);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    Intent cameroon = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    cameroon.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/cameroon");
                    cameroon.putExtra("title", "Medicament en Cameroun");
                    startActivity(cameroon);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    Intent cape_verde = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    cape_verde.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/cape-verde");
                    cape_verde.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Cape Vert");
                    startActivity(cape_verde);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    Intent congo_braza = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    congo_braza.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/congo-braza");
                    congo_braza.putExtra("title","Medicament au Congo ");
                    startActivity(congo_braza);
                    break;

                case 7:
                    Intent ivory_coast = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    ivory_coast.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/ivory-coast");
                    ivory_coast.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Côte d'Ivoire");
                    startActivity(ivory_coast);
                    break;

                case 8:
                    Intent djibouti = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    djibouti.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/djibouti");
                    djibouti.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Djibouti");
                    startActivity(djibouti);
                    break;

                case 9:
                    Intent drc = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    drc.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/drc");
                    drc.putExtra("title", "Medicament au RDC");
                    startActivity(drc);
                    break;

                case 10:
                    Intent egypt = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    egypt.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/egypt");
                    egypt.putExtra("title", "Medicament en Egypte");
                    startActivity(egypt);
                    break;

                case 11:
                    Intent eritrea = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    eritrea.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/eritrea");
                    eritrea.putExtra("title", "Medicament en Eritrea");
                    startActivity(eritrea);
                    break;

                case 12:
                    Intent ethiopia = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    ethiopia.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/burkina-faso");
                    ethiopia.putExtra("title", "Medicament en Ethiopie");
                    startActivity(ethiopia);
                    break;

                case 13:
                    Intent gabon = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    gabon.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/gabon");
                    gabon.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Gabon");
                    startActivity(gabon);
                    break;

                case 14:
                    Intent ghana = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    ghana.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/ghana");
                    ghana.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Ghana");
                    startActivity(ghana);
                    break;

                case 15:
                    Intent guinea_bissau = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    guinea_bissau.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/guinea-bissau");
                    guinea_bissau.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Guinea Bissau");
                    startActivity(guinea_bissau);
                    break;

                case 16:
                    Intent guinea_conakry = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    guinea_conakry.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/guinea-conakry");
                    guinea_conakry.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Guinea Conakry");
                    startActivity(guinea_conakry);
                    break;

                case 17:
                    Intent kenya = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    kenya.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/kenya");
                    kenya.putExtra("title", "Drugs in Kenya");
                    startActivity(kenya);
                    break;

                case 18:
                    Intent lesotho = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    lesotho.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/lesotho");
                    lesotho.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Lesotho");
                    startActivity(lesotho);
                    break;

                case 19:
                    Intent madagascar = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    madagascar.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/madagascar");
                    madagascar.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Madagascar");
                    startActivity(madagascar);
                    break;

                case 20:
                    Intent malawi = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    malawi.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/malawi");
                    malawi.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Malawi");
                    startActivity(malawi);
                    break;

                case 21:
                    Intent mali = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    mali.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/mali");
                    mali.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Mali");
                    startActivity(mali);
                    break;

                case 22:
                    Intent mauritania = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    mauritania.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/mauritania");
                    mauritania.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Mauritanie");
                    startActivity(mauritania);
                    break;

                case 23:
                    Intent morocco = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    morocco.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/morocco");
                    morocco.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Maroc");
                    startActivity(morocco);
                    break;

                case 24:
                    Intent namibia = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    namibia.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/namibia");
                    namibia.putExtra("title", "Drugs in Namibia");
                    startActivity(namibia);
                    break;

                case 25:
                    Intent niger = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    niger.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/niger");
                    niger.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Niger");
                    startActivity(niger);
                    break;

                case 26:
                    Intent nigeria = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    nigeria.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/nigeria");
                    nigeria.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Nigeria");
                    startActivity(nigeria);
                    break;

                case 27:
                    Intent rwanda = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    rwanda.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/rwanda");
                    rwanda.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Rwanda");
                    startActivity(rwanda);
                    break;

                case 28:
                    Intent senegal = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    senegal.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/senegal");
                    senegal.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Senegal");
                    startActivity(senegal);
                    break;

                case 29:
                    Intent seychelles = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    seychelles.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/seychelles");
                    seychelles.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Seychelles");
                    startActivity(seychelles);
                    break;

                case 30:
                    Intent south_africa = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    south_africa.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/south-africa");
                    south_africa.putExtra("title", "Medicament en Afrique du Sud");
                    startActivity(south_africa);
                    break;

                case 31:
                    Intent sudan = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    sudan.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/sudan");
                    sudan.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Sudan");
                    startActivity(sudan);
                    break;

                case 32:
                    Intent tanzania = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    tanzania.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/tanzania");
                    tanzania.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Tanzanie");
                    startActivity(tanzania);
                    break;

                case 33:
                    Intent tchad = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    tchad.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/Tchad");
                    tchad.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Tchad");
                    startActivity(tchad);
                    break;

                case 34:
                    Intent togo = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    togo.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/togo");
                    togo.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Togo");
                    startActivity(togo);
                    break;

                case 35:
                    Intent tunisia = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    tunisia.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/tunisia");
                    tunisia.putExtra("title", "Drugs in Tunisia");
                    startActivity(tunisia);
                    break;

                case 36:
                    Intent uganda = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    uganda.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/uganda");
                    uganda.putExtra("title", "Medicament en Uganda");
                    startActivity(uganda);
                    break;

                case 37:
                    Intent zambia = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    zambia.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/burkina-faso");
                    zambia.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Zambie");
                    startActivity(zambia);
                    break;

                case 38:
                    Intent zimbabwe = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
                    zimbabwe.putExtra("url", "http://fr.napteker.com/products/article/zimbabwe");
                    zimbabwe.putExtra("title", "Medicament au Zimbabwe");
                    startActivity(zimbabwe);
                    break;




            }
        }
    });

    //instantiating the action bar

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#436487")));



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText){


    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query){
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you have access the countries class, try adding the link & title to the country itself. It will allow the listview to just retreive the country and get the link & title from the object.

Like so:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        Countries country= (Countries) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent country_intent = new Intent(FrenchMenu.this, WebDirection.class);
        country_intent ("url", country.getURL());
        country_intent .putExtra("title", country.getTitle());
        startActivity(country_intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Edit:

So, in `Countries` : Create 2 variables for the link and title (`String link, title`). Edit the constructor and create getters and setters for those variables.

In the `FrenchMenu` class: 
Add an array `String[] links = { "The","bunch","Of","Links" }` 
And an array `String[] titles = { "the","Same","here"}`

Change your loop

```
for (int i= 0;i<countryNames.length;i++){
    Countries countries = new Countries(countryNames[i], imgs[i]);
    countrylist.add(countries);
}
```

To

```
for (int i= 0;i<countryNames.length;i++){
    Countries countries = new Countries(countryNames[i], imgs[i],links[i],titles[i]);
    countrylist.add(countries);
}
```

Then you can use the function in your `onItemClickListener` as I showed you above.

Comment: thank you robbe...sorry to ask u this am no that good in android.. as in should i create an array for the link and title within the country class, or set the getter an setters of the two and then create the array in the FrenchMenu class...thanks in advance

Comment: or should i give u the countries class too

Comment: Hi, Arnold. In my opinion I would change the setup of your `Countries` `ArrayList`. The arrays are a good way to store test data or data that wont change (in my opinion). I would move the data out of the arrays and into a file and read it in when the application needs it. But this is besides the question and it will most definitely work if you create 2 more arrays in the `FrenchMenu` class with the links and titles, create 2 variables String link and String title in the Country class and set them in your loop. If you have more questions don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: and another issue is that they are 2 classes that have to use different titles and links....so will this fit??

Comment: Normally if you overwrite the title and links when you load your ListView it should have to fit. (Assuming you mean you have 2 different activities that load countries?)

Comment: so this means i should also create the links and titles in order as i wrote the countrynames so that they match

Comment: Yes, and this is why I would separate it from your code and use (for example) an xml file so you can do  `<countries><country><name>"name"</name><img>"imagename"</img><link>"link"</link><title>"title"</title></contry>...</countries>` so you can load that and always have it in the right order. Or use a database, but something "non-hardcoded"

Comment: No problem. Good luck and have fun programming.

Comment: If there's nothing else, could you accept the answer please?

Comment: by the way is used getItem(position) rather than getItemAtPosition9(position)...thank you

Comment: and with pleasure accepting the answer... hope to refer to you in future...thx once again

Comment: You could actually remove your `getItem()` function since the `ArrayAdapter` already handles that. Like this you will always be sure the item returned will be the item which is selected in the `ListView`